# Quote from Leibniz

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I was trying to translate a quote from Leibniz:

> Nominum casus semper eliminari possunt substitutis in eorum locum particulis quibusdam.

My attempt is:

> We can always eliminate the nominal case, instead of them some particles are substituted.

How can I improve this translation to be closer to the original?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'Nomen' here means Noun. Leibnitz is explaining a version of Latin.

"The cases of nouns can always be eliminated by particles of some sort substituted in their place."

*quibusdam* is the ablative plural of quidem 'particular,' 'certain.'

'in their place,' i.e. in place of traditional cases Acc., Gen., Dat., Ablative.

Comment: In my opinion, *substitutis ... quibusdam* is an ablative absolute here, not an ablative of means. Hence I would translate, "The cases of nouns can always be eliminated if particles of some sort are substituted in their place."

Comment: I agree with David. While translating the ablative as "by" ("eliminate by") is possible in theory, I am convinced Leibniz meant it as an ablative absolute.